# Where to store application data

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, sqlite

I'm building a C#/WPF job search tracking application to keep track of resumes submitted, interviews, followups, etc and am not sure of the best way to store the data. Where/how would YOU store the data? My first thought was XML to keep it simple, but it seems like I should "model" my data since there will be lots of related bits of information. Would SQLite be a better choice? Other recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I assume you want to query and update that data I would even suggest an ORM like Entity Framework - it's easy to get started and the basic stuff like querying and updating will be very straightforward if you have worked with LINQ before - saves you the hassle of writing your own SQL queries. This also will allow you to easily extend your model later on should you decide to do so.

**Edit:**

There are self-contained light-weight alternatives that would still allow you to use LINQ:

**[SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx):**

> Microsoft SQL Server Compact is a free
>   SQL Server embedded database ideal for
>   building standalone and occasionally
>   connected applications for mobile
>   devices, desktops, and Web clients.

Here' an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36453/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-with-SQL-Server-Compact.aspx) that describes how to get LINQ to SQL to work on it. Apparently you can also [use LINQ to Entities](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/707e4a98-1a26-40d1-b8d6-63b865b5b1da) on it but there's quirks (such as design-time support) that you'll have to work around.

**[SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/):**

> SQLite is a software library that
>   implements a self-contained,
>   serverless, zero-configuration,
>   transactional SQL database engine.
>   SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL
>   database engine in the world.

There's a LINQ provider for it called [DBLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/)
As @Robert Harvey pointed out in his answer there's (almost) full support for EF since there's an ADO.NET provider for SQLLite:

> Support for the ADO.NET 3.5 Entity
>   Framework
>
> Supports nearly all the
>   entity framework functionality that
>   Sql Server supports, and passes 99% of
>   the tests in MS's EFQuerySamples demo
>   application.

Comment: Thanks. I've just learned Entity Framework and would like to use LINQ to Entities, but I'd like to find a light-weight, single file data store/provider. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BrazenTongue: Updated answer with alternatives

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you want to store the data from your application in a database.  For WPF and C#, that database is usually SQL Server or SQL Server Express, because Visual Studio 2008 easily integrates with those.

Do not use XML for this.  XML is not intended to be a large scale storage medium; the purpose of XML is to provide a common language for different computer systems to talk to each other.

SQL Server Express is usable on any Windows PC; you just need to [deploy the redistributable,](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express/redistregister.aspx) using a named instance.  See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032(SQL.100).aspx.  If it's a small application and you want to go simpler, you can use SQL Server Compact Edition, or SQLite with the [ADO.NET provider.](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Comment: OK, thanks. But I'd really rather not have to rely on a sql server instance running. I would like it to be deployable to any windows pc.